# All traffic forwarding using SSH tunnel in FreeBSD

Tags: redirect, ssh, remote-access, freebsd, network-traffic

I connect to my remote VPS like that:

```
ssh -f -C2qTnN -D 1080 username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then setup Firefox proxy setting to SOCKS5 and 127.0.0.1:1080. That's work.

Now I try to redirect all traffic from my FreeBSD to localhost:1080, but I have no idea. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect *all traffic*, do not use SOCKS5 proxy, but rather use `-w` option in `ssh`, which creates something like VPN connection and its own TUN device, which is more suitable for tunnelling system-wide traffic.

There are many examples on the internet, for example [here](http://blog.brixandersen.dk/2006/10/23/vpn-using-openssh-and-tun4-under-freebsd/). But this is really advanced use case.